# Can I trust repositories

Tags: repository, add-apt-repository

How can I trust any Repositories  like

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/tor`

or

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wagungs/Kali-linux`

Comment: GPG keys are a method of [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), and are safe enough to confirm that you did indeed download the package from where you were supposed to. Whether to trust that source or not cannot be verified by a key check (except probably keys which are universally established (eg `Ubuntu` package signing keys)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can trust them as much as you trust the people who put them up. Anyone can put up a PPA; a repository owned by some random user is obviously less trustworthy than the official LibreOffice PPA, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. The short answer is: you can't trust them.

Comment: It's a layman's answer and doesn't consider the private repository set up locally for an organisation. Nuking everything isn't the solution.